# How to start resque daemons with rails server?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, redis, resque

I wonder if there is a way to start my resque daemons when the rails server starts in my production environment. I tried creating an initializer file but it didn't work.

Every single time my rails server starts, I want to run this two commands:

```
bundle exec rake resque:work BACKGROUND=yes RAILS_ENV=production PIDFILE=/shared/pids/resque_work.pid

bundle exec rake resque:scheduler BACKGROUND=yes RAILS_ENV=production PIDFILE=/shared/pids/resque_scheduler.pid
```

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman).  You can describe what processes you need to run, and it will take care of it.

http://blog.daviddollar.org/2011/05/06/introducing-foreman.html